# Flex Tweener still being used

Tags: apache-flex, tweener

since the development of Tweener is slow I am wondering if Tweener is still the preferred lib, or if there is a different lib that is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been a huge fan of just about everything coming out of [greensock](http://blog.greensock.com/) as of late - tweenmax should just be packaged with Flex, it does just about anything you'd need it to...

Comment: yeah TweenMax looks pretty good, I'll probably switch to that